# sec_axis function in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a secondary axis in `ggplot2`. I am running the second example in http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html.

```
> p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) +
+     geom_point()
> 
> # Create a simple secondary axis
> p + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.+10))
Error in scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~. + 10)) : 
  unused argument (sec.axis = sec_axis(~. + 10))
>
```

Why is this error occurring?

Comment: Maybe update `ggplot2`? This feature was just recently introduced with 2.2.0.

Comment: To check the version of `ggplot2` you have installed type `packageVersion("ggplot2")` in the R console window.  If the version is below 2.2.0 you will need to update.  `install.pacakges("ggplot2", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com")` will install the most recent version from CRAN.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same with 2.2.1 !?! 
I got it fixed by updating my rather old (1.5 year) R version…